# Laravel user model with multiple one to one relationship

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, model

I want to set the `User` model to have a one-to-one relationship with the `Student` model as well as the `Lecture` model also.

I'm login in using the `user` table and from then it will map to the student or `lecture` table depending on the `user` type.

The problem is when I run `app\user::find('a123')->lecture` it will return the `b345(Mr Steven)` data.

And when I run `app\user::find('b345')->student`, it returns the `a123(david)` data.

Both result should have produce `NULL` because it doesnt matches the `id`.
New in Laravel thanks.

**User table**

```
id         |  password  |   type  
a123       |   1234     |   student
b345       |   1234     |   lecture
```

**Lecture table**

```
lecture_id |   id   |  name
b345       |   b345 |  Mr Steve
```

**Student table**

```
student_id |   id   | name
a123       |   a123 | david
```

**User model**

```
public function student(){
    return $this->hasOne(student::class,'student_id');
}
public function lecture(){
    return $this->hasOne(lecture::class,'lecture_id');
}
```

**Lecture model**

```
protected $primaryKey = 'lecture_id';
public function User()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class,'id');
}
```

**Student model**

```
protected $primaryKey = 'student_id';
public function User()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class,'id');
}
```

Comment: What do your migrations look like?

Comment: The id's on the lecture and student tables should be unique to themselves and should not be the same as the user_id

Comment: `->hasOne(student::class,'id','id')` but the database looks wrong, the id should be the primaryKey while the other is the forgein key